# @RequestHeader in spring not accepting fake headers

Tags: spring, annotations, request-headers

I am using

```
@RequestHeader(value = "channel") String channel
```

in Spring application controller to get headers and it works fine for normal headers, however, in some cases, I need to trap a request using filter and use HttpServletRequestWrapper to add some extra headers. The new headers added by overriding getHeader method are not being accepted by @RequestHeader annotation and throws error. However, if I manually get headers using

```
HttpServletRequest.getHeader("channel")
```

the new headers work fine. Is there any bug in @RequestHeader implementation? If so, is there any work-around so that I wouldn't have to change the same thing in 50+ APIs.

Answer (score 0):

When resolving `@RequestHeader`, Spring is using `getHeaders()`, not `getHeader()`. You need to override this one.